# How does path variable goes to params in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, web

I am asking this question cause i guess i have not good understanding over how rails params works.

i want to know how the path variable goes to rails params or mapped to key and value in rails params.
`get 'x/y/:id'` if i hit the url localhost:3000/x/y/2, here 2 will goes to params with key id: like params[id: 2]. How does it. Can anyone please help here to understand it.

Comment: (my educated guess is ) the router puts it there (the thing that parses paths and locates/invokes controllers). You can see exactly how it's done in the rails source code.

Comment: Can you please share any link where i can see how this things happen under hood

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? To understand rails specifically or understand how a similar thing can be done? If the latter, I recommend http://rebuilding-rails.com/

Comment: if you really want to get into the nuts and bolts of how it works, you need to look at the source code for ActionDispatch. In the command line of your rails app's directory, do `bundle open actionpack` and then look for the action dispatch directory. But as a Rails dev for nearly 20 years, let me caution you that this is a "rabbit hole" that you really don't need to explore. You can waste many hours on this. The top-level rails docs tell you just about everything you'll need.

Answer (score 0):

The URL `http://localhost:3000/x/y/2` results in a request to port 3000 on your Rails server something like this:

```
GET /x/y/2 http/1.1
Host: localhost
```

The server receives the request and breaks it down into its parts.

- scheme: http
- version: 1.1
- host: localhost
- port: 3000
- path: /x/y/2
- [method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods): GET

Rails compares the path to your routes, and sees it matches `get '/x/y/:id'`. 2 is set as `params[:id]`. Then it calls the controller method specified in by the route.

For more read [Rails Routing from the Outside In](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#generating-paths-and-urls-from-code) and [HTTP 1.1 Request Messages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#HTTP/1.1_request_messages).

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the answer by @schwern is right but actual thing is happen under hood
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path '/account/1', method: :get
this will convert your path to {:controller=>"books", :action=>"check", :id=>"1"}